# int object is not reversible error in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, integer

I want to reverse a list made of integers
My code:
`list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 print(reversed(list[0]))`
but it keeps saying `int object is not reversible`. I want it to print `5`

Comment: `print(reversed(list[0]))` should be `print(reversed(list)[0])` Also, don't use `list` as a variable name

Answer (score 1):

What you try to Do is to reverse the first Element of list. 
So reverse(1).This is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking python to reverse an individual int in the array, rather than the array itself.

```
>>> foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> foo.reverse()
>>> foo
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> print(foo[0])
5
```